# Meteor method waiting for subscriptions that aren't there

Tags: meteor, meteor-methods, kadira

I have a Meteor method `generateUserHash` which just passes an ID to [Intercom](https://www.intercom.com/) to get back a user hash:

```
export const generateUserHash = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'generateUserHash',

  validate() {},

  run() {
    if (!Meteor.isServer) return;

    if (!this.userId) throw new Meteor.Error('no-user-id');

    return SecureMode.userHash({
      identifier: this.userId,
      secretKey: Meteor.settings.intercom.secretKey,
    });
  },
});
```

According to Kadira:

[image]

I don't understand why it's waiting for all those subscriptions when those are nowhere inside the method.

Comment: When do you execute this method? when the app just finishes loading or on demand of user actions?

Comment: It runs while React components are mounting.

Answer (score 0):

A method will wait on subscriptions even if the subscriptions are not in that method.

A good post on wait time is here: https://meteorhacks.com/understanding-meteor-wait-time-and-this-unblock/

Comment: The link is dead. There is the web archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20160320023635/https://meteorhacks.com/understanding-meteor-wait-time-and-this-unblock/